# Get a single string with ToString() from Model that has nesting

Tags: c#

This is how the model looks:

```
public class Ingredient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal? Percentage { get; set; }
        public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public Ingredient(string name, decimal? percentage)
        {
            Name = name;
            Percentage = percentage;
            Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            string temp = Name;
            if(Percentage.HasValue)
            {
                temp = temp + " " + Percentage.ToString() + "%";
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

This is the data in  JSON format:

```
{
   "name":"paneermeel",
   "percentage":null,
   "allergen":false,
   "ingredients":[
      {
         "name":"tarwebloem",
         "percentage":null,
         "allergen":true,
         "ingredients":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"kleurstoffen",
         "percentage":null,
         "allergen":false,
         "ingredients":[
            {
               "name":"karamel",
               "percentage":null,
               "allergen":false,
               "ingredients":[
                  
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"annatto norbixine",
               "percentage":null,
               "allergen":false,
               "ingredients":[
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"zout",
         "percentage":null,
         "allergen":false,
         "ingredients":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What I want is, when I call the ToString() method on the parent node (in this case 'paneermeel') it should return the following: "paneermeel (tarwebloem, kleurstoffen (karamel, annatto norbixine), zout)"

I know I have to apply recursion here, and the list of Ingredients needs to be put between parenthesis, and each ingredient between parenthesis needs to be separated by a comma. I really can't seem to find a way to put this all together... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any attempt on your part to solve this at all. Yes, recursion would be helpful. _What have you tried?_ What _specifically_ do you need help with? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates answers to these questions, along with a detailed explanation of what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Using a little LINQ to check if the Ingredients List contains anything, and a simple String.Join, here is the working ToString().

```
    public override String ToString()
    {
        string temp = Name;
        if(Percentage.HasValue)
        {
            temp = temp + " " + Percentage.ToString() + "%";
        }
        if (Ingredients.Any()) {
            temp = temp + " (" + String.Join(", ", Ingredients) + ")";
        }
        return temp;
    }
```